# deck.gl styles certain parts of map not others

Tags: javascript, deck.gl, cartodb, maplibre-gl

I'm encountering a weird bug with my deck.gl map. The polygons all load, but some of them get colored in appropriately, while others don't. When I zoom into these uncolored areas, some more color appears, but when I zoom back out it goes away again.

Here's a chunk of my code:

```
  \\config stuff
  deckgl = new deck.DeckGL({
      container: "map",
      map: maplibregl,
      mapStyle: "https://basemaps.cartocdn.com/gl/positron-gl-style/style.json",
      initialViewState: {
        latitude: 38.302222210685656,
        longitude: -98.51898888084287,
        zoom: 4
      },
        controller: {dragPan: true, scrollZoom:true},
        layers: [
          new deck.carto.CartoLayer({
            id: 'polygons',
            connection: "carto_dw",
            type: deck.carto.MAP_TYPES.TABLE,
            data: "carto-dw-ac-whspeled.shared.polys",
            getFillColor: deck.carto.colorBins({
              attr: "time",
              domain: [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30],
              colors: [[255, 247, 236, 150], 
                        [254, 232, 200, 150], 
                        [253, 212, 158, 150], 
                        [253, 187, 132, 150], 
                        [252, 141, 89, 150], 
                        [239, 101, 72, 150], 
                        [215, 48, 31, 150], 
                        [179, 0, 0, 150], 
                        [127, 0, 0, 150], 
                        [102, 31, 31, 150], 
                        [77, 0, 0, 150]]
            }),
            getLineColor: false,
            lineWidthMaxPixels: 0,
            useDevicePixels:false
          }),
\\other layers + tooltips
```

Example:
[One city gets loaded but not the other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRsdm.jpg)

I've tried doing some optimization recommended by the documentation (turning off pickable and useDevicePixels). Not sure what else to try.

Is this a Web GL rendering issue? Is there anything I can change to make things better?

Thanks!

Comment: This can happen if your tileserver can't handle the amount of data or is timing out due to slow query responses. Do you if your query performance and return data size?